# Win7: "... the call to DllRegisterServer failed with the error code 0x80004005."

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, uac

I've searched around for answers on this topic and the one solution that keeps coming up is to run command prompt as administrator.

I'm getting the following error in Windows 7: "... the call to DllRegisterServer failed with the error code 0x80004005."

I've tried as administrator and have also tried to disable UAC as well. Any tips would be helpful.

Here's my main task: http://www.databison.com/index.php/make-mouse-scroll-wheel-work-in-vba-editor-ide/

Thanks!

[image: DLL Register Server]

Comment: You need to debug the DLL's `DllRegisterServer` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, this MS fix wouldn't work for me, but after doing some heavy googling I found this VB6 Scroll Wheel Fix buried in some comments somewhere and have been meaning to update this post for posterity reasons.

Here's the fix (Updated):

<strike>http://joebott.com/vb6scrollwheel.htm</strike>

https://github.com/jjbott/VB6ScrollWheelFix

Comment: Fantastic. Wasted ages on this and that link works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Your path name with ~'s in it ("~ALL~") may not be ideal.  An easy thing to try is to extract these files into C:\VB6mouse

Run console as admin, and try again with a path that doesn't have any uncommon characters in it.

Do you get the same error as above if you try from this new path of C:\VB6mouse?